# ¿Como obtener la ultima fila por fecha en mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Nececito obtener esta tabla: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado es una tabla con la  ultima fila por fecha donde moneda sea igual a 1.
¿ Me podrian ayudar ? desde ya muchas gracias.
intenté con:

```
select * from tabla
where pesos = min(pesos) 
and caja = 34 
and moneda = 1 
group by fecha
```

Comment: Hola LUIS, sería de mucha ayuda si pudieras explicar tus tablas como por ejemplo, cuál es su finalidad, que contenido se almacena ahí. También si pudieras agregar que es lo que has intentado hasta ahora y agregar el código.

Comment: Pon el código que has intentado

Comment: Buenas estimados..estoy simulando movimientos diarios de caja, por ejemplo en fecha 21/05 ingresaron 4150 pesos en mi caja ( 34) por una transferencia con numero de movimiento 27 y fue el unico del dia.  Luego se reflejan los ingresos y egresos de los otros dias..necesitaria obtener el ultimo movimiento de cada dia, que en el ejemplo serian las filas con numero 27 , 33 y 36.

Comment: Intenté con select * from tabla where pesos = min(pesos) and caja = 34 and mon2da = 1 group by fecha

Comment: Luis edita tu pregunta y pon el código ahí

Comment: Edite la pregunta y agregué el codigo

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! La tabla que queres obtener, que logica tiene con respecto a los datos? yo veo que son 3 registros cualquiera. Si no explicas la logica, no vamos a saber como hacer lo que vos queres...

Comment: necesito obtener el ultimo detalle de cada dia reflejado en la tabla,  tengo datos de tres dias en la tabla: el dia 21/05 tengo una sola fila,... para el 22/05 tengo cuatro filas...  para le dia 28/05 tengo  dos filas.  yo necesito la ultima fila de cada dia donde la moneda sea igual a 1.  (la moneda es representada con  1 para pesos, 2 para dolares y 3 para euros)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select *
from (select max(numero)
from tabla
where moneda = 1
group by fecha) t1 inner join tabla t2 on t1.numero = t2.numero;
```

Dentro de la **cláusula** **from** se hace esta consulta:

```
select max(numero)
from tabla
where moneda = 1
group by fecha
```

La cual nos va a devolver el último registro ingresado por cada fecha, donde además la moneda sea igual a **1**, **max(numero)** indica precisamente el numero máximo por cada grupo de fecha, que sería en efecto el último registro introducido para esa fecha. A esta consulta dentro de la **cláusula** **from** se le da como **alias t1**.

Posteriormente haremos un **inner join** a la misma tabla para obtener todos los campos que deseemos, que en este caso son todos, esta junta de tablas se hace por el **campo numero**, enlazando solamente los registros que coinciden por su **campo numero.**

Por último quedan seleccionados todos los campos.

Comment: Muchas gracias Japv ! ya pude obtener los resultados que queria.  la sub consulta era  la salucion.  nuevente gracias.  saludos

Comment: @LUISLAVAYÉN, si la respuesta te fue útil te agradecería que le dieras un voto y marcaras como aceptada, gracias